# Expo build: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try to build .apk file via expo I get the error like:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at renderIntentFilterDatumEntries (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidIntentFilters.js:33:17)
    at /app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidIntentFilters.js:37:70
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at renderIntentFilterData (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidIntentFilters.js:37:48)
    at /app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidIntentFilters.js:25:9
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at renderIntentFilters (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidIntentFilters.js:22:24)
    at runShellAppModificationsAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:632:115)
    at async Object.createAndroidShellAppAsync (/app/turtle/node_modules/@expo/xdl/build/detach/AndroidShellApp.js:392:3)
    at async runShellAppBuilder (/app/turtle/build/builders/android.js:95:9)
    at async Object.buildAndroid [as android] (/app/turtle/build/builders/android.js:43:28)
    at async build (/app/turtle/build/jobManager.js:181:33)
    at async processJob (/app/turtle/build/jobManager.js:118:32)
    at async Object.doJob (/app/turtle/build/jobManager.js:49:5)
    at async main (/app/turtle/build/server.js:66:13)
```

In test and develop mode, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [expo build does not work](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-build-does-not-work/39764)

Specifically check next answer:

> For anyone else experiencing this issue, make sure you’re formatting your intent filter >property correctly. The proper format is shown here- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#intentfilters